# Json response array to viewModel - Swift 5

Tags: swift

I need to assign my response to a new array but I don't know how to do it. I mean I have a request which gets a response (array) but in viewModel i have to assign it to new array to have possibility to display my data in tableView. However I don't know how to do it:

My model:

```swift
struct EventModel: Codable {
    let id, title, subtitle, date: String?
    let imageURL: String?
    let videoURL: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, title, subtitle, date
        case imageURL = "imageUrl"
        case videoURL = "videoUrl"
    }
}
```

And here's my fetch request where I'm getting my data:

```swift
          do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let jsonData = try decoder.decode([EventModel].self, from: data)
                print(jsonData.count)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(.success(jsonData))
                }
            } catch let error {
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }
        dataTask?.resume()
```

Up to this moment is fine when I use print(jsonData.count) i'm getting 16 which is correct but when I have to pass it to viewModel I'm stuck.

Alsi my viewModel where I have to assign my response to a newly created array and I don't really know how to fix that.

```swift
class EventViewModel {

    private var eventService = EventService()

    private var eventsArray = [EventModel]()


    func fetchEventsData(completion: @escaping () -> ()) {

        eventService.getEvents { [weak self] (result) in

            switch result {
            case .success(_):
                self?.eventsArray
     // here I have to pass my response to new array (eventsArray) somehow but i dont know how
                completion()
            case .failure(let error):
                // Something is wrong with the JSON file or the model
                print("Error processing json data: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At the end my json looks like this (contains 16 elements):

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "title": "title",
    "subtitle": "subtitle",
    "date": "2023-12-11T03:08:17.231Z",
    "imageUrl": "some url"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "title": "title",
    "subtitle": "subtitle",
    "date": "2022-10-11T01:08:17.231Z",
    "imageUrl": "some url"
  },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer for my question is:

I was missing a `result.get()` in assigning part.

It should be:

```swift
eventService.getEvents { [weak self] (result) in
     switch result {
     case .success():
        self?.eventsArray = result.get()
     case .failure(let error):
        print("Error processing json data: \(error)")
     }
}
```